# How to get iOS 13 WiFi SSID using Ionic3?

Tags: ios, ionic3, ios13

I have used WifiWizard plugin to get SSID but it's not working on iOS 13. It gives me SSID as "Wi-Fi" key word, it's not showing actual connected WiFi SSID.

I have add Location when in use key in info.plist and also tried to update native iOS code but it's not working.

I have tried with WifiWizard2 plugin but this is also not working.

```
getWifiName() {
    WifiWizard.getCurrentSSID(ssidHandler => {
      console.log(ssidHandler);
      ssidHandler = ssidHandler.toString().replace("\"", "");
      ssidHandler = ssidHandler.toString().replace("\"", "");
      this.connectedTo = ssidHandler;
      this.ssidHandler(ssidHandler);
    }, fail => {
      this.goToSettingsButton = false;
      console.log(fail);
    });
  }
```

I want current WiFi SSID in iOS 13 like if I connect to ABC Wifi network then it should give me SSID as ABC.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hey I had the same issue and solved it by installing `cordova-plugin-geolocation`. [Here's the official site](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation)

It's basically ->

**Notice here I'm installing specific versions because of my ionic 3.20.1**

`$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation@3`

`$ npm install @ionic-native/geolocation@4.10`

```js
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

...

constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {}

...

async yourAwesomeFunction() {
 try {
   pos = await this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
   if (pos) WifiWizard.getCurrentSSID((ssid) => {
   //your stuff
});
 } catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
})
```

Then add this to the `config.xml`:

```
<config-file overwrite="true" parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
     <string>Allow the app to know your location</string>
</config-file>
```

Afterwards I added the library `CoreLocation` (General's XCODE tab) to the project.

Comment: I have tried this but not giving me WiFi SSID, it goes into fail state and give me "Not Available" response. I have an issue with iPhone 11 (iOS 13.1.3).

Comment: but when I run same on iPhone XS MAX (iOS 13.1.3) is gives me SSID. Please help me to resolve this issue.